# subversion: batching up create-directory changes into a single commit

Tags: svn

I want to do

```
svn mkdir http://svn.mydomain.com/.../projectX/trunk
svn mkdir http://svn.mydomain.com/.../projectX/branches
svn mkdir http://svn.mydomain.com/.../projectX/tags
svn propset someprop someval http://svn.mydomain.com/.../projectX
svn propset anotherprop anotherval http://svn.mydomain.com/.../projectX
```

*in a single commit.* Is there a way to batch up svn operations on the repository server? I could swear I've seen a way to do this before, but I can't remember the magic words to use or to google.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. you can create multiple directories in a single commit:

   svn mkdir -m "a single commit" /path/to/folder_1  /path/to/folder_2

   However, you cannot propset directories in the same commit :-(
2. You can also use **svnmucc** to combine repository actions in a single commit, however also here you cannot propset directories which are not already inside the repository.

So you can minimize the number of commits to 2 (I left out the -m switch for the log message):

```
svn mkdir http://svn.mydomain.com/.../projectX/trunk http://svn.mydomain.com/.../projectX/branches http://svn.mydomain.com/.../projectX/tags
svnmucc propset someprop someval http://svn.mydomain.com/.../projectX propset anotherprop anotherval http://svn.mydomain.com/.../projectX
```

If you still want a single commit, you have to check out a working copy and do all manipulations and commit afterwards

Comment: yay! I knew I had seen a command like this someplace. svnmucc was it! where's the manual for it? I can't seem to find it.

Comment: I never found more than the build in help

Answer (score 7):

You could always `svn checkout` the projectX directory, `mkdir` trunk/branches/tags locally then `svn add` them (or just use `svn mkdir` locally rather than on the URL, which does the same thing), set the properties and then issue a single `svn commit`.

Comment: That's the way to do it, but you have to `svn add` the created directories before changing their properties. After all that, you are ready to commit everything in one revision increment.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the answer you're looking for, but if you were to check out your root directory to a working copy, then executed `svn mkdir trunk`, `svn mkdir branches`, `svn mkdir tags`, and then did your `svn commit` then those directory creations would be batched.